# How do I get all the permutations selecting one item from each value list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, permutation

Friends, basically, I want to take a dict:

```
fruit_dict = {'oranges':['big','small'],'apples':['green','yellow','red']}
```

And get the following list of dictionaries by having all possible permutations between all values of different keys:

```
output_list = 
[
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'yellow'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'red'},
{'oranges':'small','apples':'green'},
{'oranges':'small','apples':'yellow'},
{'oranges':'small','apples':'red'}
]
```

How to do it? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't the permutations, but the [Cartesian product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Think of it like a nested loop.

```
from itertools import product

fruit_dict = {'oranges':['big','small'],'apples':['green','yellow','red']}    

keys, values = zip(*fruit_dict.items())
print [dict(zip(keys, value_list)) for value_list in product(*values)]
```

Then you just need to create a new dictionary using your existing keys and each item from the product.

Comment: Thanks a lot, agf! Works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

using `itertools.product()`:

```
In [94]: dic = {'oranges':['big','small'],'apples':['green','yellow','red']}

In [95]: sort_values=[x[1] for x in sorted(dic.items())]  #sorted values based on keys

In [96]: [dict(zip(sorted(dic.keys()),x)) for x in product(*sort_values)]
Out[96]: 
[{'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big'},
 {'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'small'},
 {'apples': 'yellow', 'oranges': 'big'},
 {'apples': 'yellow', 'oranges': 'small'},
 {'apples': 'red', 'oranges': 'big'},
 {'apples': 'red', 'oranges': 'small'}]
```